# The balance problems and possible workarounds for two legged war machines

Tags: warfare, weapons, robots, weapon-mass-destruction

I'm becoming a experimental weapons designer and mechanical engineer. I already have two designs for weapons I will build, one being a very heavy set of mechanical armor, and another being a four legged, tank like machine piloted by two man teams. The four legged machine will be very heavy and slow, so I wanted to shift gears to creating designs to two legged, light and fast units. I have the cockpit and tower designs down, but all robots that have been created to run or walk at high speeds have always had balance problems. So what could be some doable methods to minimize these balance problems and maybe even increase the movement speed of the legs themselves. Ive worked out that hydraulics are powerful, but slow, so I don't want that to have to be what powers such a fast machine.

Comment: What's wrong with just handwaving it and saying that the engineers worked out the balance issue during the development process?

Comment: I hate to say it, but these questions have been answered quite thoroughly in the many BattleTech, MechWarrior, Gundam, etc., stories and universes.  Gyroscopes, electromagnetic leg actuators, etc.  So much has been written about battle robots over the last 30 years that it might be difficult to come up with something original.

Comment: Hydraulic actuators are not inherently slower than other actuator technologies; it's just that hydraulic actuators are commonly used when there is a need for great force or torque to move heavy shafts, levers and loads, and heavy objects have a lot of inertia. For example, [micromanipulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromanipulator) often use hydraulics.

Comment: "I'm becoming a experimental weapons designer and mechanical engineer." You mean that you're becoming an artist, not an engineer, right ?

Comment: No, I'm designing, and are going to build them.

Comment: Regarding the speed of hydraulics, a [hydraulic breaker](http://indeco-breakers.com/hydraulic-breakershammers/model-selection-tool/) can strike with about 34 kJ energy up to 8 times per second. So that is a lot of energy delivered very quickly. I think hydraulics are plenty fast.

Comment: "Ive worked out that hydraulics are powerful".  That is not correct.  For a couple of years there I built large robotic-like devices in the 6-7 figure cost range (for an Asian enterprise); the downside of hydraulics is **just unreliability**. Linear (and rotational) actuators from Kohlmorgen or whatever are simply "more K.I.S.S.".  Hydraulics are awesome, faster in most domains, stronger and better in most ways - except mess/reliability. As soon as you start building, you'll come to the same conclusion as other engineers!  Enjoy.

Comment: "So what could be some doable methods to minimize these balance problems...." you're asking about the single, most difficult, problem facing mankind currently and for the next say 300 years ..... advanced robotics AI-locomotion.  As a starting point, what about reading *Precambrian Intelligence* by Rod Brooks.  Cheers!

Comment: Best solution: add another leg to the two-legged models to increase balance.

Comment: There’s one inherent problem with <del>AT-AT’s</del> two-legged walkers. Whatever happens, make sure nobody with rope gets close to them.

Comment: @MicahDaCanon this particular site is for artists, why don't you ask https://robotics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a site for creating fictional worlds. If you're wanting to create real robots this isn't the site for your question.

Comment: @sphennings Althugh it is an interesting question with some specific answers, I tend to agree that it is on the wrong site. It can't be fictional if it is being built in reality. But since I gave an answer I can not vote to close.

Comment: This is an active research area. If you want it to move naturally and with any sort of speed at all you should get access to research libraries and read up on the current progress people are making. This is not a simple task and requires a lot of code, mathematics or Advance AI's to get working.

Answer (score 5):

Check out what Boston Dynamics has done for mobility with legs.

https://www.bostondynamics.com/

As far as I know, they are leading the bleeding edge of tech on this front.

They use hydraulics for the power, so they prove you can have both power and speed with hydraulics.

They use Lidar and other sensors to keep balance.  I'm assuming you could use a flywheel and other gyroscopic devices to help.

There are other robotics that solve balance problems, like Segway robots and the emergency response robots being developed for the NIST program.

https://www.nist.gov/el/intelligent-systems-division-73500/response-robots

Going off what these groups have done, you don't need any handwavium or reference to other, fictional examples to make your robots work.

Comment: My favorite video  Shows [Atlas doing a *backflip*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRj34o4hN4I).  Two legged motion without a few million years of evolution is tough, but we're getting better at it.  (And personally, what I find amazing is the first outtakie that appears at the end of the clip, where Atlas doesn't stick the landing and takes a few steps to control itself).

Comment: That being said, I think there *is* a challenge to be solved, which is scaling up the robots.  The OP doesn't specify what size these 2 legged robots should be, but larger things have to be inherently more stable in order to move quickly.  That could still be an interesting challenge for Boston Robotics.  And, of course, there's the [Skynet Syndrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAmyZP-qbTE) to deal with.

Comment: You beat me to posting it!  It's incredible, right?  And, scary.

Comment: BTW I had not seen the backflip video - thanks for that @CortAmmon!

Comment: @CortAmmon My quadruped design fits a two pilot team and could punch the top window out of a two story house. The two legged one is just a little smaller than that with only one pilot.

Comment: @CortAmmon,I'll have to take a look at those videos when I can listen to them, especially the parody.  The OP could design some large and some small bots, depending on use.  The human sized ones could definitely be a 1:1 for Boston Dynamics.  People use Robotis kits to make martial arts robots, for tiny bots. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotis_Bioloid  I've also seen movie exosuits and similar made for real, but I can't find them ATM.

Comment: @computercarguy These are going to be pilotable robots similar in size to what you see in the BattleTech series of games.

Comment: The coolest thing about this is that as technology improves, the robots will become more and more viable from an investment perspective, which will hopefully in turn lead to an increased rate of improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You will always be stuck with the center-of-gravity issue with two legged designs. The fighting two-legged robots all have huge treads at their base, and the power module is in the base of each leg. So are they still two legged if they have huge tank treads for feet? Essentially, they have two broad units on the ground, and the two 'legs' are just support for the weapons mounts and turrets.

That is, the mass is all very low, and well within the tipping radius.

Once the center of gravity goes beyond the base, no amount of hydraulics or power or quickness will stop it from tipping. The 'righting' force has to be applied outside of the center of gravity and the tipping point. A gyroscope might slow it, but will not prevent it.

Humans, when we walk, are usually falling forward (unless we shuffle), and the free leg is moved out in front to stop the fall. Then we pivot, and fall forward again. Unless we are standing still, our enter of gravity is always outside of the base of our foot (or feet, if we are jumping). But that severely limits our maneuverability of our upper torso when walking.

That's why skiers use ski poles.

And maybe your two-legged robots should as well.

See for instance [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-ouLX8Q9UM) recent robotic duel. Advisory warning to cyborgs: contains graphic images and gratuitous violence against robots.

Comment: I watched this video a while ago, which was the inspiration for my quadruped design due to the instability of using treads like they did. But of course, anything is possible to overcome such problems. My initial design answer to this problem was a series of very heavy weights to move around inside the machine and control the location of the center of gravity to compensate for the weight on the other side.

Comment: Sort of like what they do in side car racing.

Comment: Exactly. It would adjust the center of gravity as well as the leg positioning to make up for weight imbalances.